# How to use specific apply method in implicit Json `reads` from Scala

Tags: json, scala, implicit

I have a class that takes a few optional `Enumeration` types in its constructor:

```
case class GPMedia(id: Option[GPID], created: Option[DateTime], active: Option[Boolean], data: Array[Byte], mimeType: Option[GPMediaType.Type], encoding: Option[GPEncoder.Codec], compression: Option[GPCompressor.Type])
```

I've been struggling to create an `implicit Json reads` method that works. I keep ending up with errors such as:

```
[error] /Users/zbeckman/Projects/Glimpulse/Server/project/glimpulse-server/app/utility/GPMedia.scala:57: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
etc...
```

What I'm trying to do is translate the inbound Json strings, turning them into the right kind of `Option` instance (eg., a MIME type "image/png" in the Json would turn into `Option(GPMediaType(v))`. The GPMediaType constructor will map the string, and return a correct value (one of which is `GPMediaType.Unknown`).

Here's the `implicit reads` that I've worked up so far, implemented on the GPMedia class' companion object...

```
case object GPMedia extends GPRequestLogging {
    implicit val reads: Reads[GPMedia] = (
        (__ \ "id").readNullable[GPID] and
            (__ \ "created").readNullable[DateTime] and
            (__ \ "active").readNullable[Boolean] and
            (__ \ "data").read[Array[Byte]] and
            (__ \ "mimeType").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPMediaType(v))) and
            (__ \ "encoding").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPEncoder(v.get))) and
            (__ \ "compression").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPCompressor(v.get)))
        )(GPMedia.apply _)
}
```

This works, but when I try to add other `apply()` methods, it all goes to heck. How can I apply a **specific** apply method in the Json `reads` implementation? For example, when I add this `apply` method:

```
def apply(data: Array[Byte]) = new GPMedia(None, None, None, data, None, None, None)
```

I end up with:

```
[error] /Users/zbeckman/Projects/Glimpulse/Server/project/glimpulse-server/app/utility/GPMedia.scala:60: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method apply in object GPMedia of type (id: Option[models.GPID], created: Option[org.joda.time.DateTime], active: Option[Boolean], data: Array[Byte], mimeType: Option[utility.GPMediaType.Type], encoding: Option[utility.GPEncoder.Codec], compression: Option[utility.GPCompressor.Type])utility.GPMedia
[error] and  method apply in object GPMedia of type (data: Array[Byte])utility.GPMedia
[error] match expected type ?
[error]         )(GPMedia.apply _)
```

I've tried a few different approaches, such as `(GPMedia.apply(...))` but I can't seem to get the parameters right.

I'm new to the whole Json implicit reader/writer and Json decoding syntax. Clearly I'm missing something here...

**Edit**

Here's another example, regarding my attempt to call a specific `apply` method:

```
implicit val reads: Reads[GPMedia] = (
    (__ \ "id").readNullable[GPID] and
        (__ \ "created").readNullable[DateTime] and
        (__ \ "active").readNullable[Boolean] and
        (__ \ "data").read[Array[Byte]] and
        (__ \ "mimeType").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPMediaType(v))) and
        (__ \ "encoding").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPEncoder(v.get))) and
        (__ \ "compression").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPCompressor(v.get)))
    )(v => GPMedia.apply(v.id, v.created, v.active, v.data, v.mimeType, v.encoding, v.compression))
```

This results in:

```
[error] /Users/zbeckman/Projects/Glimpulse/Server/project/glimpulse-server/app/utility/GPMedia.scala:60: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : utility.GPMedia
[error]  required: (Option[models.GPID], Option[org.joda.time.DateTime], Option[Boolean], Array[Byte], Option[utility.GPMediaType.Value], Option[utility.GPEncoder.Value], Option[utility.GPCompressor.Type])
[error]     (which expands to)  (Option[models.GPID], Option[org.joda.time.DateTime], Option[Boolean], Array[Byte], Option[utility.GPMediaType.Value], Option[utility.GPEncoder.Value], Option[utility.GPCompressor.Value])
[error]         )(v => GPMedia.apply(v.id, v.created, v.active, v.data, v.mimeType, v.encoding, v.compression))
[error]                             ^
```

Comment: Is it not possible to rename your apply function and call it from the read ?

Comment: Yes, but the point is, I'd like to have `apply()` methods throughout the code so that we don't have to use `new` and some very un-Scala syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The compiler does not know which `apply` method to use. This is just one of the caveats of using overloaded methods. The only way you can make this like "nice" is to rename the methods, or alias the overloaded `apply` methods with different names and use those.

---

Your second attempt does not work because the compiler is expecting a function with a signature similar to `apply`, like:

```
(Option[GPID], Option[DateTime], Option[Boolean], Array[Byte], Option[String], Option[String], Option[String]) => GPMedia
```

But you're trying to use:

```
GPMedia => GPMedia
```

Which doesn't work, because we don't yet have a `GPMedia` object, just the tupled fields. It would look more like:

```
implicit val reads: Reads[GPMedia] = (
    (__ \ "id").readNullable[GPID] and
    (__ \ "created").readNullable[DateTime] and
    (__ \ "active").readNullable[Boolean] and
    (__ \ "data").read[Array[Byte]] and
    (__ \ "mimeType").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPMediaType(v))) and
    (__ \ "encoding").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPEncoder(v.get))) and
    (__ \ "compression").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPCompressor(v.get)))
).tupled.map(v => GPMedia.apply(v._1, v._2, v._3, v._4, v._5, v._6, v._7))
```

Which does not look good. Usually we can make it look better like this:

```
implicit val reads: Reads[GPMedia] = (
    (__ \ "id").readNullable[GPID] and
    (__ \ "created").readNullable[DateTime] and
    (__ \ "active").readNullable[Boolean] and
    (__ \ "data").read[Array[Byte]] and
    (__ \ "mimeType").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPMediaType(v))) and
    (__ \ "encoding").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPEncoder(v.get))) and
    (__ \ "compression").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPCompressor(v.get)))
).tupled.map(v => GPMedia.apply _ tupled v)
```

**Except** that you will end up with the same problem that you started with, because the compiler will not be able to choose the correct `apply` method. So you really have no choice but to rename or make things ugly.

Comment: Thank you – That does help a lot. It didn't even occur to me that I could use a completely different method, versus `apply`, which makes sense. I think I'll give that a try. The real goal is to allow the "public API" to have a nice set of constructors (meaning, `apply` methods)... if I can find a way to get all the implicit reads/writes and Slick to survive that, I think we'll be in good shape.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible.

But You need to specify all the parameters required for the overloaded apply method `using _: ParameterType` like I have done below and it will work.

```
implicit val reads: Reads[GPMedia] = (
    (__ \ "id").readNullable[GPID] and
      (__ \ "created").readNullable[DateTime] and
      (__ \ "active").readNullable[Boolean] and
      (__ \ "data").read[Array[Byte]] and
      (__ \ "mimeType").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPMediaType(v))) and
      (__ \ "encoding").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPEncoder(v.get))) and
      (__ \ "compression").readNullable[String].map(v => Option(GPCompressor(v.get)))
    ) (
    v => GPMedia.apply(
      _: GPID,
      _: DateTime, 
      _: Boolean,
      _: Array[Byte],
      _: Option[GPMediaType],
      _: Option[GPEncoder],
      _: Option[GPCompressor]
    )
  )
```